# Spark app failing with error org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running spark 2.4.0 on EMR. I am trying to process huge data (1TB) on EMR using 100 NODES with memory 122G and 16core each. i am getting below exceptions after sometime. Here are the parameters I've set.

```
--executor-memory 80g
--exeuctor-cores 4 
--driver-memory 80g
--driver-cores 1

spark = (SparkSession
            .builder
            .master("yarn")
            .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true")
            .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled","true")
            .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
            .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors","50")
            #.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "500")
            .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout","2m")
            .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "16g")
            .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2047")
            .config("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "2047")
            .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true")
            .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","50g")
            .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
            .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout","1200")
            .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","200")
            .config("spark.memory.storageFraction","0.3")
            .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","2g")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate())
```

Here is the three type of executor failures I've been getting and eventually causing the corresponding Stage to rerun. Sometimes the rerun succeeds and sometimes they go on retrying forever.

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 8

org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failure while fetching StreamChunkId{streamId=45963765394, chunkIndex=0}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Executor is not registered (appId=application_1625085506598_0885, execId=137)

org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to ip-10-40-6-235.ap-south-1.compute.internal/10.40.6.235:7337
```

attaching the screenshot of spark dag [image]